# What are the differences between the photometric options for GDAL_merge?

Tags: gdal, color, gdal-merge

I am using GDAL_merge to merge several geotiff tiles into one large tile. One of the creation options I can add is photometric.
There are several options for this.

- MINISBLACK
- MINISWHITE
- RGB
- CMYK
- YCBCR
- CIELAB
- ICCLAB
- ITULAB

What are the differences between these different outputs? I understand the MINISBLACK and MINISWHITE options, but the others are less clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The chosen value is stored in the PhotometricInterpretation TIFF tag, which defines the color space, i.e. how to interpret the values of the bands. Example for a 3-band GeoTIFF defined as RGB: band 1 = red, band 2 = green, band 3 = blue. CMYK stands for the Cyan, Magenta, Yellow, blacK color space, etc.

Comment: Do you also know what the "LAB" values stand for? Can they also be related to different colors?

Comment: You might wish to read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space